# Determining status of itunes subscription from webserver

Tags: ios, web-services, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I have some subscription-based content that should be accessible to the user from their iOS app and from the website as well. My understanding of in-app purchases (IAP) on iOS is that I have to set up some "products" in the App Store that the user then "subscribes to" from the app. Apple provides functionality (detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573)) on how to check subscription status from within the app in this case.

My question is :

- What if i want to allow the user to access their subscription on the website ?
- Is there a way to check the status of an IAP subscription in the App Store to see whether it is active or not from my web server ?

It's not clear from Apple's documentation whether this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

[Validating Receipts With the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1)

This is the documentation from apple on how to validate a receipt with iTunes. This does not necessarily have to be done from iOS. Once you send the receipt data to your web service you can make the same call directly to iTunes from there as well.

So to answer you questions:

1- Once you validate the receipt with iTunes from web, you can upgrade the user account to have a subscription.

2- You can validate the receipt data with iTunes whenever you like, in the response from iTunes one of the fields is the latest user receipt. This will allow you to check if the user still has an active subscription or not.